# php 5.2 repository

Tags: php, centos, yum, repository

I'm quite a noob at configuring servers. Anyway, I'm running CentOS 5 and I've been meaning to install the php-xml package for my PHP 5.2.17. This server runs proprietary software which requires PHP 5.2 to be installed and not 5.3.

Currently, I was using the atomic repo. But when i do a yum install php-xml it want to update all php packages to bleeding edge version of 5.3.6. I don't want that - I want to leave it as it is and install php-xml 5.2.17.

So I've downloaded the php-xml package by itself and tried to install it when it threw an error saying:

```
Examining php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm: php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64
Marking php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.2.17-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1 for package: php-xml
--> Processing Dependency: libexslt.so.0()(64bit) for package: php-xml
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1()(64bit) for package: php-xml
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.17-2.el5_2.2 set to be updated
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.2.17-1 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1 for package: php-xml
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64 from /php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64 has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1 is needed by package php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64 (/php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.17-1 is needed by package php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64 (/php-xml-5.2.17-1.x86_64)
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                    package-cleanup --dupes
                    rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Even though I checked and I do have php-common 5.2.17-1 installed like the rest of PHP packages.

So I figure that I need a repository which delivers 5.2.17 php packages, is that right? Couldn't find it by myself.

Thank you for any info on what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

```
pear install XML_Parser # try to install it via pear not rpm
```